# Autocorrelation AR(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, autocorrelation, stationarity, autoregressive

I am doing a self-study question. I need to find the autocorrelation $\rho(2)$ for the following AR(1) process:

$y_t = y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t;\\
\epsilon_t \sim (0,\sigma_\epsilon^2) $

For that I need to calculate the expect value, variance, and covariances for the AR process.

Nevertheless, I suspect that is a not stationary time serie. In such situation, I have to take the first difference to reach the stationarity of the distribution:

$\delta (y_t - y_{t-1}) = (y_{t-1} - y_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t;\\
z_t = \epsilon_t$

How do I obtain the $\rho(2)$ now?

Comment: How did you take the first difference? The equations look unfamiliar.

Comment: You are correct that it's not stationary.  But it should be clear that the autocorrelation still depends only on the lag and not on the time.  Show this; and then you may compute the autocorrelation by starting at any time you please, such as $t=0.$

Comment: @RichardHardy I did a mistake. The correct should be $\delta (y_t - y_{t-1}) = y_{t-1} - y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t;\\
z_t = \epsilon_t$

Comment: Consider editing your post to correct the mistake.